# SignalR can't reconnect to server in JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have a JavaScript client that connected to SignalR hub. First time its connect fine, and everything works (messages send succesfully):

```
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:31:06 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:31:06 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Negotiating with '........'.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:31:06 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: SignalR: Initializing long polling connection with server.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:31:15 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to '.......' using longPolling.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:31:15 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Longpolling connected
```

After 1 minutes, it try to reconnect, but fails:

```
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:32:15 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = error. 
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:32:15 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: SignalR: Initializing long polling connection with server.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:32:15 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to '.......' using longPolling.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:32:45 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (30000ms), disconnecting.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:32:45 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Aborted xhr requst.
js/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js (10) :[14:32:45 GMT+0900 (KST)] SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.
```

On the server side I just enable cross domain connection and everything else is default.

What can be wrong?

Comment: are you connecting from a pc, a tablet, a mobile phone? What browser version?

Comment: also the SignalR version would be heplful

Comment: It would be helpful in identifying the problem if you post the code as well.

Comment: Define "I try to reconnect". What exactly are you doing? Are you getting errors on the Hub on the back end?

Comment: @vtortola 1.1.3 maybe? :D

Comment: @Max there are a lot, really a lot of possible situations with this output. So any answer will be potentially wrong. But 2.0 version got a lot of fixes so I suggest to try it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to, avoid using different domains/subdomains to start, this causes a fall-back to long-polling, and websockets might establish a more reliable solution. You'll need to run the server-side on Windows 2012 to get the full benefits of it. They did fix a lot of problems in 2.0 and they made the api a lot simpler and they have sample code for reconnections on server drops out-of-the-box. Your problem might originate from the server having a timeout of 1 minute per request, which you can increase in IIS. For me, adding a virtual application under my main application solved a lot of problems. Might be helpful to record communication with the server using Fiddler if you still have a problem after this to see what the server actually returns.